# Got Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within the 5000ms timeout specified by jest.setTimeout

Tags: api, testing, jestjs, web-api-testing

I have problem with api-testing with jest

**What is the current behavior?**

```
 Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within the 5000ms timeout specified by jest.setTimeout.
      at ../../../../Users/chhoeurng.sakona/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/jest-cli/node_modules/jest-jasmine2/build/queue_runner.js:68:21
```

My current code

```
it ('GET should return a status of 200 OK', function (done) {
        frisby
            .get('url-api')
            .expect('status', 200)
            .done(done);
    });
```

**What is the current behavior?**
`It should work normally and no error.`

**Please provide your exact Jest configuration**
`I do not have configuration`

**Run `npx envinfo --preset jest` in your project directory and paste the
results here**

```
 System:
    OS: Windows 10
    CPU: x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-7700 CPU @ 3.60GHz
  Binaries:
    Node: 8.11.1
    Yarn: Not Found
    npm: 5.6.0
   jest v22.4.3
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to return a promise or use an async function when woking with promises:

```
it ('GET should return a status of 200 OK', async() => {
        await frisby
            .get('url-api')
            .expect('status', 200)

    });
```

or

```
it ('GET should return a status of 200 OK', function () {
        return frisby
            .get('url-api')
            .expect('status', 200)

    });
```

Also have a look at the [docs](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/tutorial-async.html)

Comment: Hi Andreas, I still got that error when I use your second code. The first block of code is not correct. Please could you help for this.

Comment: Now I try to use this change this line then it works `it ('GET should return a status of 200 OK', async (done) => {`

Comment: Could you help me, I do not know where my code wrong, and it still turn timeout.

`const frisby = require('frisby');
const Joi = frisby.Joi; // Frisby exports Joi for convenience on type assersions

it ('Should sakona return a status of 200', function (done) {
    return frisby
        .get('url-api')
        .expect('status', 200)
        .expect('json', 'status', '3')
        .expect('jsonTypes', 'merchants*', { // Assert *each* object in 'items' array
            'uid': Joi.number().required(),
            'category': Joi.string().required(),
        })
        .done(done);
`

Comment: the best way is to dont use `done` after all, as it is not needed when working with async function as described in my answer. I will update the code to make it more clear